# Linq Entity - Expression Function In Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, expression

I´m making a databinding a ASPxGridview  with mode EntityServerModeDataSource (the [demo](https://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/databinding/LargeDatabase.aspx) ) I'm using a Entity Framework (ef6) like source of data and i´m loading the grid with a Linq expression:

```
    protected void EntityServerModeDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, DevExpress.Data.Linq.LinqServerModeDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
    e.QueryableSource = from emps in MyEntity.TableEntities
                                    join y in MyEntity.SubTableEntities
                                    on emps.IDTableEntities
                                    equals y.IDTableEntities
                                    join z in MyEntity.TblAcessProfiles on 1 equals z.IDAccessProfiles
                                    join z1 in MyEntity.TblAccess on z.IDAccess equals z1.IDAccess


                                    select new
                                    {
                                       emps.Field1,
                                       emps.Field2,
                                       emps.Field3,
                                       y.Field1,
                                       y.Field2
                                    };
    }
```

I need filter the results of the query with some functions that currently i've in SQL. I used the functions in the where clause by calling them directly to SQL (emdfunctions):

```
 [DbFunction("EntityModel.Store", "GetAccess")]
    public static int GetAccess(string LogUserInfoAccess,string InfoEntidad,string AccessTextToFind)
    {

        throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");
    }



  e.QueryableSource = (   from x in from emps in MyEntity.TableEntities
                          join y in MyEntity.SubTableEntities
                          on emps.IDTableEntities
                          equals y.IDTableEntities
                          join z in MyEntity.TblAcessProfiles          
                          on 1 equals z.IDAccessProfiles
                          join z1 in MyEntity.TblAccess 
                          on z.IDAccess equals z1.IDAccess             
                where ((z1.AccessTxt == "AccessName") &&
                         GetAccess(
                              "AccessOfUSerLog",
                              y.EntityInfo,
                              z.Access
                             )) == true
                         select new
                         {
                             emps.Field1,
                             emps.Field2,
                             emps.Field3,
                             y.Field1,
                             y.Field2
                         });
```

The LogUSerInfoAccess field contain all the accesses of the user to check,
    a access of the InfoEntidad  have to agree with same access of the loguser access. The AccessTextToFind is the name of the access to find.
SQL Definition:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetUserAccess](@LogUserInfo varchar(MAX), @CheckUserInfo varchar(MAX),@AccesoInfo varchar(MAX))
```

RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN

```
DECLARE @contA int 
DECLARE @contB int
DECLARE @contC int
DECLARE @auxA int = 1
DECLARE @auxB int
DECLARE @auxC int
DECLARE @KeyA varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @KeyB varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @KeyC varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @auxOK int = 0
DECLARE @auxClaves int = 0

SET @contA = convert(int, [dbo].[SplitASG](@AccesoInfo,';',0))

WHILE @auxA <= @contA
BEGIN
    SET @KeyA = dbo.splitASG(@AccesoInfo,';',@auxA)
    SET @auxB = 1
    SET @contB = convert(int, [dbo].[SplitASG](@LogUserInfo,';',0))
    WHILE @auxB <= @contB
    BEGIN
        SET @KeyB = dbo.splitASG(@LogUserInfo,';',@auxB)
        IF [dbo].[SplitASG](@KeyB,'=',1) = [dbo].[SplitASG](@KeyA,'=',1) 
        BEGIN
            SET @auxC = 1
            SET @contC = convert(int, [dbo].[SplitASG](@CheckUserInfo,';',0))
            WHILE @auxC <= @contC
            BEGIN
                SET @KeyC = dbo.splitASG(@CheckUserInfo,';',@auxC)
                IF [dbo].[SplitASG](@KeyC,'=',1) = [dbo].[SplitASG](@KeyA,'=',1) 
                BEGIN
                    SET @auxClaves = @auxClaves + 1
                    IF (CHARINDEX(','+[dbo].[SplitASG](@KeyB,'=',2)+',', ','+[dbo].[SplitASG](@KeyA,'=',2)+',') > 0 AND CHARINDEX(','+[dbo].[SplitASG](@KeyC,'=',2)+',', ','+[dbo].[SplitASG](@KeyA,'=',2)+',') > 0)
                    OR CHARINDEX(',-1,', ','+[dbo].[SplitASG](@KeyA,'=',2)+',') > 0
                    OR (CHARINDEX(',-2,', ','+[dbo].[SplitASG](@KeyA,'=',2)+',') > 0 and CHARINDEX(','+[dbo].[SplitASG](@KeyB,'=',2)+',', ','+[dbo].[SplitASG](@KeyC,'=',2)+',') > 0)
                    SET @auxOK = @auxOK + 1
                END
                SET @auxC = @auxC + 1
            END
        END
        SET @auxB = @auxB + 1
    END

    SET @auxA = @auxA + 1
END
    RETURN case when @auxOK = @auxClaves then 1 ELSE 0 END END
```

That's it ok, but the performance is very very bad. I thought that my solution is have the function in c sharp and call them from a where clause of the linq query. 
So I've passed the function to .NET:

```
    public static int GetUserAccess(string LogUserInfo, string CheckUserInfo, string AccesoInfo)
{
    int ContA;
    int ContB;
    int ContC;
    int AuxA = 1;
    int AuxB;
    int AuxC;
    string KeyA;
    string KeyB;
    string KeyC;
    int auxOK = 0;
    int auxClaves = 0;


    ContA = Convert.ToInt32(SplitASG(AccesoInfo, ";", 0));
    while (AuxA <= ContA)
    {
        KeyA = SplitASG(AccesoInfo, ";", AuxA);
        AuxB = 1;
        ContB = Convert.ToInt32(SplitASG(LogUserInfo, ";", 0));
        while (AuxB <= ContB)
        {
            KeyB = SplitASG(LogUserInfo, ";", AuxB);
            if (SplitASG(KeyB, "=", 1) == SplitASG(KeyA, "=", 1))
            {
                AuxC = 1;
                ContC = Convert.ToInt32(SplitASG(CheckUserInfo, ";", 0));
                while (AuxC <= ContC)
                {
                    KeyC = SplitASG(@CheckUserInfo, ";", AuxC);
                    if (SplitASG(KeyC, "=", 1) == SplitASG(KeyA, "=", 1))
                    {


                        auxClaves += 1;

                        if ((("," + SplitASG(KeyA, "=", 2) + ",").IndexOf("," + SplitASG(KeyB, "=", 2) + ",") > -1
                    &
                    ("," + SplitASG(KeyA, "=", 2) + ",").IndexOf("," + SplitASG(KeyC, "=", 2) + ",") > -1)

                    | (",-1,").IndexOf("," + SplitASG(KeyA, "=", 2) + ",") > -1

                    | ((",-2,").IndexOf("," + SplitASG(KeyA, "=", 2) + ",") > -1 &

                    ("," + SplitASG(KeyC, "=", 2) + ",").IndexOf("," + SplitASG(KeyB, "=", 2) + ",") > -1

                    ))
                        {
                            auxOK += 1;
                        }
                    }
                    AuxC += 1;
                }
            }
            AuxB += 1;
        }
        AuxA += 1;
    }
    return auxOK == auxClaves ? 1 : 0;
}
```

I know the only way to call a .NET function from that where is a expression function, I've searched a lot of documentation but I'm not able to call it properly.

```
    var query = (from emps in MyEntity.TableEntities
                                    join y in MyEntity.SubTableEntities
                                    on emps.IDTableEntities
                                    equals y.IDTableEntities
                                    join z in MyEntity.TblAcessProfiles on 1 equals z.IDAccessProfiles
                                    join z1 in MyEntity.TblAccess on z.IDAccess equals z1.IDAccess


                                    select new ClassResult
                                    {
                                       emps.Field1,
                                       emps.Field2,
                                       emps.Field3,
                                       y.Field1,
                                       y.Field2
                                    }
).AsQueryable().Where(GetAccess);

 public Expression<Func<ClassResult, bool>> GetAccess
{                                      
  return e => e.Field.. ;       
}
```

I am not able to call the function from the function expression, I can not put more than one line in the body ... I would need some documentation or some example, to use the where I need in linq, apologize for such a long question.
Greetings and thank you

Comment: What is the aim of this function? It seems that an underlying problem is bad data normalization, because you need all these splits.

Comment: 472/5000
The function must perform a somewhat complex task, a user's access is defined as something like this:
IDField3 = 1; IDField2 = 2; IDField1 = 23. (The numbers are IDs, if the number is -1 or -2 there is a different operation).
The function should check if permissions:
IDField3 = 1; IDField2 = 2; IDField1 = 23 have something in common with another string:
IDField3 = 1; IDFIeld4 = 2; IDFIeld4 = 33
In this case the common is IDField3 and verify that that IDField3 is in the access we want to check.

Comment: As I suspected, this would be much easier (and *way*  quicker) if these data were stored in a normalized table design, like `User 1..n IDField`. Nothing you can do about it now, I guess, but porting the function to C# is a dead end. That's certainly not going to be faster.